# How can I split a string in an array of strings such that each string is either a predefined array of strings, a variable or a string in Matlab?

Tags: string, split

I have two predefined arrays, say:

```
first = ["alpha" "beta"];
second = ["{" "}"];
```

and I want to create a function which receives a string and splits the string in different string arrays(or cell). Each array(or cell) should contain either a single member of one of the two arrays, a variable that is not a member of the arrays (without including the blank space) or a string. Ex:
Input string:

```
"alpha{ beta} new {} new2 "This is a string" }"
```

Output string:

```
"alpha" "{" "beta" "new" "{" "}" "new2" "This is a string" "}"
```

Hope it is clear!

Bests,
Stergios

I tried this:

```
S = "alpha{ beta} new new2 {} new3}";
T = ["alpha","beta", "{","}"];
[X,Y] = strsplit(S,[T " "], 'CollapseDelimiters',false);
X = strtrim(X); % you forgot to mention, that you also want to remove whitespace
X(2,:) = [Y,""];
X(strlength(X)==0) = []
```

but S does not accept strings of strings and if I use '' every word will be in a different cell!

Comment: Do you know if each element of S will have the same number of resulting elements? If so, you could use string's split method. Otherwise, I think you'll have to loop or use cellful.

Comment: I would say yes if you treat the strings elements (like above "This is a string") like one string.
Do you mean cellfun?